# Javascript sort array by a list of ranks

Tags: javascript

I have some experience in sorting JS arrays with basic values but this one has me stumped.  I have an array of firefighter objects, each object has a `rank:` property as well as the usual properties like `firstName: foo, lastName: bar`

I want to sort the array by the firefighters rank, however the ranks don't follow an alphabetical order.  I would like them sorted in the following order:

```
CFO - Chief Fire Officer
DCFO - Deputy Chief Fire Officer
SSO - Senior Station Officer
SO - Station Officer
SFF - Senior Firefighter
QFF - Qualified Firefighter
FF - Firefighter
RFF - Recruit Firefighter
OS - Operational Support
```

I haven't tried anything yet, I have no idea where to start.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just compare each item's rank's `indexOf` in the array above? Use a `map` for greater efficiency?

Comment: There will be multiple of each rank and I want them group together in that order.

Comment: I don't see the issue, should still work just fine..? Post the input if you want

Comment: please show the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you first need a reference for the rank of the officer, the higher the greater the weight. So let's make a hash and order it in some way of the ranks. For this I'll choose an descending order since you've provided that already:

```
let ranks = {
  CFO: 1,
  DCFO: 2,
  SSO: 3,
  SO: 4,
  SFF: 5,
  QFF: 6,
  FF: 7,
  RFF: 8,
  OS: 9
}
```

Next we want to organize our array of officers by their rank so we'll need a comparison function

```
compareRank( left, right ){
  return ranks[left.rank] - ranks[right.rank]
}
```

next we need to sort our array by the sort function

```
let sortedOfficers = officers.sort(compareRank)
```

They will now be sorted in descending order(really ascending, however we gave higher ranks lesser value, so it is reversed).

---

Another ways to sort would include concatenating of lists ranks in the order you wanted to sort them based on the ranks you wanted to do

```
function fieldIs(key, value){ return function(object){ return object[key] == value } }

let sortedOfficers = [].concatenate(
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'CFO'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'DCFO'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'SSO'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'SO'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'SFF'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'QFF'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'FF'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'RFF'),
  officers.filter(fieldIs('rank', 'OS')
)
```

This method, while more verbose and ***much slower***, is a little more adaptable since you could easily compose the parts based on an input ordered array of values for the field to be

```
function fieldSort(field, orderedValues, things){
  return  [].concatenate(
    ...orderedValues.map(value =>
      things.filter(
        fieldIs(
          field,
          value
         )
      )
    )
}
```

---

There are of course may other ways to sort, but these are just a few examples to help show that if you have some sort of definition of order, you can sort based on that order. Now the real question becomes how would you combine the two methods based on the idea that using `Array.prototype.reduce()` on the `orderedValues` array could be used to create that hash in the first example?

Let's try it:

```
function fieldSort(field, orderedValues, things){
  let valueHash = orderedValues.reduce((acc, value, index) =>{
      acc[value] = index
      return acc
    },
    {}
  )
  return things.sort((left, right) =>
    valueHash[left[field]] - valueHash[right[field]]
  )
}
```

The good news about this third option: It removes all of the looping form the second option. It loops only as much as needed to sort + one loop over the ordered array. This make it much faster than the second example by taking the ideas from the first example.

Comment: _This method, while more verbose..._ I don't mind the verbosity so much as the O(n^2) time complexity vs. `.sort()`'s O(n log n) time complexity. I upvoted for the first approach though, as that's exactly what I would have done. A nice little snippet you could consider including would be how to convert an array of ranks to the object you have at the beginning, like this: `const ranks = ['CFO', 'DCFO', ...].reduce((ranks, rank, index) => Object.assign(ranks, { [index]: rank }), {})`

Comment: I left that out specifically since it's something I wanted to add as an extra 'think some more' thing... but... meh. I might just add that in. The second method is slow, yes, but is a way that more people are used to thinking about it. I should add a disclaimer

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be a bit more complicated than a basic sort, awesome answer.